# Python: Storing List Objects Externally

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently running a project with a workflow in the following form:

An input goes through a slow (95% of programme runtime) process to form an output list (`data`). Fast operations are then performed on the list to create a final output.

Is there a sensible way I can store `data` externally to my python script so that I can run the slow process once and then trial the final stages (reading  `data` in rather than reassembling it)?

EDIT: Considered exporting to 'simple' formats (MS Excel / MySQL) which proved unhelpful as the strings were both too long and contained special characters.

Comment: Yes, there are many ways of persisting data with Python - what have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: Write it to a file? Store it in a database? Pickle it? Run your "slow" code in an interpreter and then work on the object the interpreter still has in memory? Yes, of course there are numerous ways to do this. What are you asking?

Comment: you mean like a file? Look in to `pickle`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it appears `pickle` was what I was searching for (thanks to corn3lius and Two-Bit Alchemist for their comments).

A simple example (reproduced from https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingPickle):

```
# Save a dictionary into a pickle file.
import pickle
favorite_color = { "lion": "yellow", "kitty": "red" }
pickle.dump( favorite_color, open( "save.p", "wb" ) )

# Load the dictionary back from the pickle file.
import pickle

favorite_color = pickle.load( open( "save.p", "rb" ) )
# favorite_color is now { "lion": "yellow", "kitty": "red" }`
```

Comment: As long as you keep in mind that unpickling is unsafe; there are several pure-text serialization formats suitable for use.